# Cucumber PendingExceprion for test steps in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Erly I asked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807402/nosuchmethoderror-after-run-junit-test-with-cucumber) question about cucumber and java.
After correct my project, I checked PendingException in cucumber-junit. I have 2 classes: TestClass.java for working with SoapUI, TestSteps.java for implementation cucumber steps with my code and JUnit Run.java class.
This is my code:
TestClass.java:

```
    public class FirstTest {
private static String xmlFile;
private static String projectPath;

public FirstTest(String file)
{
    xmlFile = file;
}
//for Then step
public static void run() throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException {
    //add test project
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(getProjectPath());
    //add xml file for test into property
    project.setPropertyValue("File", xmlFile);
    //get TestSuite and TestCase by name
    TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("Test");
    TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Test");
    //run test
    testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);

}

public static String getProjectPath()
{
    return projectPath = "path";
}
```

}

And this is TestSteps.java class:

```
    public class TestSteps {
private FirstTest testClass;

@Given("^I have a file \"(.*?)\"$")
public void i_have_a_file(String file) throws Throwable {
    testClass = new FirstTest(file);
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I want to run case$")
public void i_want_to_run_case() throws Throwable {
    testClass.run();
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

}

Cucumber feature:

```
    Scenario: Test
Given I have a file "path_to_file"
Then I want to run case
```

And JUnit Class:

```
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = {"junit:target_junit/cucumber.xml"},
glue = {"src/com.teststeps.TestSteps"},
features = {"Feature"},
dryRun = true,
strict = true,
tags = {},
monochrome = true)

public class RunTest {
}
```

If I try run JUnit Class, I checking PendingException:

```
cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailure(JUnitReporter.java:134)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailureOrIgnoreStep(JUnitReporter.java:122)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:280)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

But I just implemented this steps in my java files. In what direction to look? Why can I check this exception?
UPDATE:
Try this code in Eclipse too, it dosen't work.
Somebody know reasons?
UPD 2: Edit descriptions
UPD 3: Recreate project help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove `throw new PendingException();` from your steps.

Comment: There really ought to be text in the default template that says "remove this when step is implemented" because it's really not clear what the point of that throw is.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing explicitly an Exception in your code.

Remove the line below:

```
throw new PendingException();
```

The `throw` keyword in Java is used to explicitly throw an exception from a method or any block of code. We can throw either checked or unchecked exception.

The `throw` keyword is mainly used to throw custom exceptions.

Example syntax to throw an exception: `throw new ArithmeticException("/ by zero");`